# Запуск приложения QtQuick

Tags: qt, qtcreator, qml

Я создаю проект на QtQuick в QT Creator 4.3.1 без использования ui формы.
Вот дерево проекта:
[image: дерево проекта]

Вот код файла main:

```
    import QtQuick 2.6
    import QtQuick.Window 2.2

    Window {
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
        title: qsTr("Hello World")

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                console.log(qsTr('Clicked on background. Text: "' + textEdit.text + '"'))
            }
        }

        TextEdit {
            id: textEdit
            text: qsTr("Enter some text...")
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.topMargin: 20
            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: -10
                color: "transparent"
                border.width: 1
            }
        }
    }
```

Программа запускается и работает.
Теперь я хочу избавиться от Window и заменить его например на Rectangle:

```
import QtQuick 2.6

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 200; height: 200;
    color: "#ffffff"
}
```

И тут программа перестаёт запускаться вообще, то есть ничего не происходит.
Помогите пожалуйста.